# Flutter modal bottom sheet overelay

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

How do you create the card overlay effect as shown on a screenshot using a `showCupertinoModalBottomSheet` in Flutter? I tried different configurations, and the only working appears when you call `showCupertinoModalBottomSheet` 2 times.

**What is expected and required:**
[image]

**Current result:**
[image]

```
if (context.mounted) {
        showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            enableDrag: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            builder: (context) => MyVerification(
                  verificationUri: verificationUri,
                ));
      }
```

Comment: [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) works, but it is a third party library.

Comment: @Elevo do you have a suggestion on how to use this library to achieve this? i have experimented with it, and did not succeed

Comment: use `showCupertinoModalBottomSheet` in`Widget build(BuildContext context)`, and make a bool variable to control the showing state.

Comment: @Elevo not really helpful, as this is what I do